# Autolayout ignoring navigation bar in runtime

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5, uinavigationbar, autolayout

I am using autolayout to design my xib file. The layout I designed looks like below in the xid:

portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

It is okay for me. The uisearch bar under the navigation bar and the table view under it. The second tableview on the left side of the first table view.

But when I running it. It looks like below:

Portrait: (UISearch bar goes under navigation bar on the runtime)

[image]

Landscape: (Some of UISearchBar goes under navigation bar)

[image]

**Edit**

I had set below constraints for `uisearchbar`:

1- Equal width, searchbar and tableview (the bigger one)

2- Leading alignment (62) - searchbar and tableview (the smaller one)

3- Horizontal Space- View- searchbar

4- Vertical space- (2)- searchbar- top layout guide

5- Vertical Space- Table view (the bigger one) - saerch bar

Also you can see all constraints in below image:

[image]

why it looks different in xib and when I run?

I checked every code about navigation bar too, there is nothing that looks bad.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Auto Layout is not implemented properly. How did you set constraints for the ```UISearchBar```? After iOS 6, it is so much easier to do it on Storyboards. Try removing auto layout and see the difference.

Comment: Please see my edit, I am not sure it is about constraints. If constrains be wrong they should now look right and blue in the xib.

Comment: I checked every code about navigation bar too, there is nothing that looks bad. Is there any idea why it is looking so?

Comment: Is the search bar a subview of your table? If so it could be a content inset issue

Comment: no it is a subview of the uicontroller's view